# I can't display my table (codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have searched this site for the answer, but all the answers i got didn't work.

**MODEL:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model_product extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
         // Initialization of class
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function viewauction()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('producten')->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
         // Initialization of class
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_product');
        $data ['query'] = $this->model_product->viewauction();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Beschrijving</th>
        <th>Prijs</th>
        <th>Vooraad</th>
        <th>Categorie</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
        <tr> 
        <td><?php echo $row->naam; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->beschrijving; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->prijs; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->producten_op_voorraad; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->categorie; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get a empty output. no error's
I have 1 item in the table.

To be sure here is the database file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'webshop';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: try to print $data['query'] and be sure you getting data.

Comment: i put it in the view. does nothing

Comment: write print_r($data);die(); at your controller after this line $data ['query'] = $this->model_product->viewauction(); and what you see at browser

Comment: Array ( [query] => Array ( ) )

Comment: It seems you are not getting data from database.try to echo $this->db->last_query() and make sure that query is OK. try run the query at sql server see if you are getting data.

Comment: as you may already know i run it local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems a type in `table name` make sure table with `producten` name is present in db

and your config is missing `$db['default']['username'] = '';` you need to a username, generally it will be `$db['default']['username'] = 'root';` on localhost

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('producten')->get();
```

you can get result using just

```
$query = $this->db->get('producten');
```

Comment: it was the username. the most stupid mistake i could make. Thank you everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, try this:

```
function viewauction()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('producten');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Note that `$this->db->get('tablename')` is the standard syntax of `select * from table` query in Codeogniter Active Records Class. Please check this out: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Additionally, you can try this in your controller, to check whether all the data are coming from your query inside the array `$data['query']`:

```
$data ['query'] = $this->model_product->viewauction();
//do the following to check whether you got the data correctly from your query and inside the array.
$echo "<pre>";
print_r();
die();
```

**Edit - 1:**

If my solution doesn't work, then I'm pretty sure the problem is with your database config file. I've a few observations and questions:

1. Why are you using the address `'127.0.0.1'` in your database default hostname? Isn't `'localhost'` a better option?
2. Why don't you have a username for your database? Usually in mysql the default username is `root`. I think you should set `$db['default']['username'] = 'root';`
3. Is your database name correct? Is it really `'webshop'`?

I'm pretty much sure the problem is somewhere out here. Please check.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you wrote makes no sense. If he's not getting results with $query->result() (which gives you back an array of objects) by no way he'll get anything with ->result_array() (which gives you back the same array of objects but in an array form way)

Answer (score 0):

I would attack the problem from the root up, and FIRST OF ALL, activate the debug database. As you're in localhost AND ONLY WHEN YOU'RE IN LOCALHOST, active the debug database from codeigniter: Change this line in your config dabase.php:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

And run it again, if there exists a database problem it'll arise.

If not, go checking where you have problems:

**First:** Make sure your query will take results: As @Shaiful Islam points out, first check what sql sentence you run, and if that gives you back result:

```
function viewauction()
{
   $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('producten')->get();

   $results = $query->result();

   echo $this->db->last_query();

   return $results;
}
```

This will give you back the SQL you're running, and you can run it directly and check if you're receiving results from the SQL.

**Second:** If you run the SQL and get data, print it in the controller to check if they work correctly:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('model_product');
    $data ['query'] = $this->model_product->viewauction();

    // Check the data:
    var_dump( $data['query'] );

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

**Third**: If above went well, last thing is checking data in the view: In the first line of the file, write:

```
<?php var_dump($query); ?>
```

With all that, you should know where the data are missed, and with that, it'll be easy to know where the problem is.

Comment: i ran the first 2 but i don't get any data in the code from my controller. i ran the SQL code i got in the database and i got the info i wanted to print